# Multiple for loops

Tags: java, loops

Is it possible to combine multiple for loops into one loop in Java?

e.g, I have

```
for (i : lista)
{
 //do something
}

for (j : listb)
{
 //do something
}
```

is it possible to combine both in one?

Comment: what does *combining* means here ? nesting ?

Comment: Yes, I wanted both the loops in the "same line".. if that makes sense..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your question only makes sense when lista and listb are of equal size, right?
Then you could say something like

```
for (int k=0; k<lista.length; k++)
{
  int i = lista[k];
  int j = listb[k];
  // do something
}
```

Comment: there's a nice function in python, zip; zip(lista, listb) would create [(lista_0, listb_0), (lista_1, listb_1), ...] not sure if something similar exists in Java; might fit into the spirit of your question

Comment: Hi Nicolas.. what I meant was getting both the loops in the same line.. I have a List, so I use list.add() function inside the loop..

Comment: I'm not sure the question only makes sense if the lists are of equal size.  Certainly he can combine the two lists and make a single pass without this assumption.  I'm not down-voting - this is just a side note.

Comment: James: thanks for accepting; you might want to provide a bit more context though if you feel that's not quite what you want. there's more ambiguity in your question than I initially realized (Amir: I interpreted the question in a particular way but you're right, there's different ways of interpretation)

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the loops, but the only way to concatenate them is to write one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Not too long ago I had a task where I needed that.

I parsed every pixel of an image and generated in the same `for` loop another image.

```
for(int a = 0, b = 0; a < 10 && b < 20; a++, b+=2) 
{ 
    /*...*/ 
}
```

Comment: what's the semantics of the comma in a < 10, b < 20 ? AND? that might produce some funny effects...

Comment: The loop condition `a < 10, b < 20` won't compile. It needs to be a boolean expression and `,` is not a boolean value.

Comment: @TedHopp: Corrected it. I was thinking in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The most readable way to do this is to combine the two lists into one and iterate.

```
List<String> combinedList = new ArrayList<String>(listOne);
combinedList.addAll(listTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested for loops

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<0;j++){

        }
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be about nested loops.